# mono xbuild fail error : Error building target GetReferenceAssemblyPaths: UNC paths should be of the form \\server\share

Tags: c#, mono, xbuild

I have a solution which I can build without any issue. However my co-worker gets the  following error:

```
error : Error building target GetReferenceAssemblyPaths: UNC paths should be of the form \\server\share
```

We both have the same version of mono installed. What else in the our environments could be causing the issue?

Here is the output on my machine:

```
XBuild Engine Version 14.0
Mono, Version 4.6.1.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors

Build started 01/02/2017 12:32:33.
__________________________________________________
Project "E:\path\WindToolsService.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):
    Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
        Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
    Target Rebuild:
        Project "E:\path\myproject\myproject.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
            Target CoreClean:
                Deleting file 'E:\path\myproject\obj\Debug\.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78.AssemblyAttribute.cs'
                Deleting file 'E:\path\myproject\obj\Debug\myproject.dll'
                Deleting file 'E:\path\myproject\bin\Debug\myproject.dll.mdb'
                Deleting file 'E:\path\myproject\bin\Debug\myproject.dll'
                Deleting file 'E:\path\myproject\bin\Debug\protobuf-net.dll'
                Deleting file 'E:\path\myproject\obj\Debug\myproject.dll.mdb'
                Deleting file 'E:\path\myproject\obj\Debug\myproject.csproj.FilesWrittenAbsolute.txt'
            Target PrepareForBuild:
                Configuration: Debug Platform: AnyCPU
            Target CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
                Copying file from 'E:\path\packages\protobuf-portable-net.2.0.0.668\lib\portable-net45+wp8+win8\protobuf-net.dll' to 'E:\path\myproject\bin\Debug\protobuf-net.dll'
            Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
            No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.
            Target CoreCompile:
                Tool C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin\mcs.bat execution started with arguments: /noconfig /debug:full /debug+ /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\myproject.dll IMessage.cs IMessageCallbackLookup.cs IMessageLookup.cs IMessagePubSub.cs Message.cs MessageCallbackLookup.cs MessageCallbacks.cs MessageLookup.cs MessageLookupFactory.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs TestMessages.cs obj\Debug\.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78.AssemblyAttribute.cs /target:library /define:"DEBUG;TRACE" /nostdlib /reference:..\packages\protobuf-portable-net.2.0.0.668\lib\portable-net45+wp8+win8\protobuf-net.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\mono\xbuild-frameworks\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile78\\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (.......
```

Here is the output on the failing machine:

```
XBuild Engine Version 14.0
Mono, Version 4.6.1.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors

Build started 01/02/2017 14:46:49.
__________________________________________________
Project "C:\path\WindToolsService.sln" (Rebuild target(s)):
        Target ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
                Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
        Target Rebuild:
                Project "C:\path\myproject\myproject.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
                        Target PrepareForBuild:
                                Configuration: Debug Platform: AnyCPU
: error : Error building target GetReferenceAssemblyPaths: UNC paths should be of the form \\server\share.
                Done building project "C:\path\myproject\myproject.csproj".-- FAILED
                Project "C:\path\Portable.Reprogramming\Portable.Reprogramming.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)):
                        Target PrepareForBuild:
                                Configuration: Debug Platform: AnyCPU
```

Comment: Incidentally, we installed monodevelop (xamarin studio) on the failing machine, and we can build fine from there. But, still not from xbuild

Comment: Stop wasting your time on Mono on Windows. On Windows use MSBuild and MSBuild will be cross platform and used on Linux and more soon. Xamarin Studio simply uses MSBuild instead of xbuild.

Comment: @LexLi, thanks I had been wondering that. What is the purpose of xbuild? Is it just for building in linux environment?

Comment: xbuild has a relatively short life cycle. It was started as a GSoC project for Mono and later became an official part to simulate MSBuild, but always lacks many features as MSBuild grew too fast. Last year Microsoft open sourced MSBuild, so now the focus has been moved to better port MSBuild to other OSs to replace xbuild.